# mysql varchar length/values

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am busy building an database (mysql) and want to start of with good practice for this database design.

- `Varchar(255)`   vs.    `Varchar(50)`

I just would like to know, if my website which reads from the database would have an performance dip if i define a column `user_name` varchar(**255**) and not varchar(**50**), especially if the database grows significantly ?

I have read a guy saying that for `MySQL` the data value is always default **255** , which then in that case it would be unnecessary defining the table anything under **255**? If you can maybe explain in depth how this has a influence on the website performance or not?

Also this will this be the same for integer, date etc..

Any expert advise on this will be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: performance is based on if you have a LOT of columns/rows and if the db is properly indexed. 255 and 50 lengths have nothing to do with this.

Comment: `50` or `255` length will not affect your performance. Its just showing the max length for that column and will occupy only with the character length.

Comment: @Fred-ii- So basically you telling me if i have a user_name varchar(255) and 20 0000 entries in my database as user_name , and call it to a webpage the performance would be the same if lets say i declared it as user_name varchar(50)? And lets say my db is probably indexed. For some reason i cant think that its the same..

Comment: mysql is more powerful than you may think

Comment: Basically what i thought is if i store it as varchar(255) the database reserves space for user_name varchar(255) characters which is more than varchar(50) so i thought calling to webpage it would have a performance impact..like the answer for this post here, "will consume more memory than you have to using MySQL. This affects cache efficiency, sorting speed, etc." , do you agree @Fred-ii- ?

Comment: `varchar(255)` is mostly used for say passwords, or email addresses. As far as the memory issue goes; I tend to not agree with that since depending on the server and most of today's machines have enough memory to handle this. It's not like you'd get billions of requests for the same row at the same time, unlike Facebook for instance which uses a different engine and UUID also, and that's a totally different animal there. Memory usually gets dumped when it's no longer in use but that's a totally different subject/animal. I'd run a benchmark.

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- , if i may ask , what do you find as number one way to run MySQL benchmark ?

Answer (score 1):

Declaring the column as `varchar(50)` or `varchar(255)` has the same performance.
There's one possible performance impact: in **MySQL**, temporary tables and MEMORY tables store a `VARCHAR` column as a fixed-length column, padded out to its maximum length. If you design VARCHAR columns much larger than the greatest size you need, you will consume more memory than you have to. This affects cache efficiency, sorting speed, etc.

Comment: im using MYSQL, im a bit confused, you say varchar(255) and varchar(50) has the same performance, but then you say "if you design VARCHAR columns much larger than the greatest size you need, you will consume more memory than you have to" which would impact the web performance right?